# Advice on lens for Glidecam

Tags: canon, lenses

I was asked to video a wedding. Here are my lenses: 50mm f1.8, 10-18 f4.5-5.6, 18-135 f3.5‑5.6. Camera is a Canon 3ti.

I'm thinking about renting a glidecam hd 1000, and my question is, will the 10-18 be good enough, or do I need a faster lens for better results since there might be times when light is low? For example, a canon 20mm f2.8 or 24mm f2.8 or Tokinha 11-16 f2.8 or even a 24-70 or 24-105. Also, does the IS play a big role here?

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to my mind: If you never operated or balanced a Glidecam before you will probably have a hard time. When using a Glidecam IS will not make such a big difference but nonetheless there will be one. So better have IS.

I am assuming that you are using a DSLR like the Canon EOS 5D Mk III.
Especially the 5D has quite good low light capabilities. Faster leses are generally speaking good but keep in mind that you need to pull focus manually and that you need several meters depth of field. So you might be good to go with what you have.

Comment: Thanks @Max. I wish I had a 5D Mk III, but no, it's just a humble t3i, which obviously not going to do as well in low light. As to the glidecam, correct, I have never operated or balanced one, but would you say if I could practice for a day or two I would do fine, or is it that difficult?

Comment: I rented the Glidecam for in of my own productions. I used the Blackmagic Pocket Cinema Camera and could not balance it in approx 30min. We had several issues that prevented me from training. I would recommend at least a whole day of training. Also: watch tutorials on YouTube